# Is photon antibunching a requirement for quantum key distribution?

Tags: photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics

While reading up on single photon sources I often came across photon antibunching being a requirement that had to be demonstrated for a specific single photon source. I understand that antibunching behaviour arises from the fact that the radiative excited states in single photon sources have a specific lifetime and therefore cannot emit while there are either no excited states that decay radiatively or while those states simply do not decay due to their mean lifetime.

So the essence of my question is: Are antibunching experiments merely to prove that a source is in fact a single photon source or is antibunching a requirement/beneficial for certain applications (like QKD).

Comment: Antibunching experiments are meant to prove that a source is providing single photons. The idea is that you send a light source onto a beam splitter and you check how often you have a signal leaving both ports of the beam splitter. With a single photon source, the photon can never be detected on both output ports. With a coherent light source (such as a laser), there will always be some probability of detecting a photon on both output ports.

Answer (score 0):

Photon antibunching demonstrates a specific property (indistinguishability) of a specific quantum information carrier (photons).

Most quantum protocols, such as QKD, are not tied to any specific implementation, so photon antibunching is not directly related to them: one could in principle implement a QKD protocol using something different than photons as information carriers.

Even restricting to a quantum optical context though, the answer is no.
The reason is that antibunching witnesses the *indistinguishability* of a pair (or more) of photons, which is not a fundamental property in many protocols.
If, for example, a protocol requires the use of a Bell state $|00\rangle+|11\rangle$, and the qubits are encoded into the polarization of a pair of photons, then the indistinguishability of such photons is not required.